# How to order by date defaultdict(list) value?

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'003': [('Biology', 'A', '04/18/2013'), ('Irdu', 'A'
, '04/17/2013')], '002': [('Biology', 'A', '03/01/2013'), ('Math', 'C', '01/10/2
013'), ('Math', 'C', '03/10/2013')], '001': [('Biology', 'B', '05/01/2013'), ('L
iterature', 'B', '03/02/2013'), ('Math', 'A', '02/20/2013')]})
```

I want to sort each key by date and get the following output

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'003': [('Irdu', 'A', '04/17/2013'), ('Biology', 'A', '04/18/2013')], '002': [('Math', 'C', '01/10/2013'), ('Biology', 'A', '03/01/2013'), ('Math', 'C', '03/10/2013')], '001': [('Math', 'A', '02/20/2013'), ('Literature', 'B', '03/02/2013'), ('Biology', 'B', '05/01/2013')]})
```

I tried the following but did not work any idea ?

```
accounts = defaultdict(list)
sortedData = sorted(accounts.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(2))
```

Comment: The example output that you showed is not a sorted version of the original, it's mutated; the tuples haven't been sorted, you've actually just changed the dates in them.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want something like :

```
key = itemgetter(2)
sortedData = {}
for k, v in accounts.items():
    v.sort(key=key)
    sortedData[k] = v
```

or

```
sortedData = {(k, list(sorted(v, key=key)) for k, v in accounts.items()}
```

Comment: Cool. Thank you. I ended up using this solution.

Comment: hmmm @dugres I thought sort by date was working well. But looks like it is not. Any idea ?

defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'11163722404385': [('#3', 'Biology', 'A', 'Mon Apr 22 13:32:00 PDT 2013'), ('#3', '2089','Irdu', 'B', 'Wed Apr 10 15:31:00 PDT 2013')], '1116372240485': [('#3', '2089','Biology', 'C', 'Mon Apr 25 13:32:00 PDT 2013'), ('#3', '2089', 'Math', 'A', 'Mon Apr 22 13:31:14 PDT 2013'), ('#3', '2089', 'Literature','C','Mon Apr 22 13:31:00 PDT 2013')]})

getter = operator.itemgetter(3)
for v in accounts.itervalues():
   v.sort(key=getter)

Answer (score 1):

`iteritems` returns an iterator of key/value pairs. If you want to use it, you'll have to skip the keys and sort the values. If you want to actually modify the defaultdict itself, an in-place sort would be best:

```
getter = operator.itemgetter(2)
for v in accounts.itervalues():
    v.sort(key=getter)
```

If you want a new defaultdict, you can use a generator expression:

```
getter = operator.itemgetter(2)
sortedData = defaultdict(list,
    {k: sorted(v, key=getter) for k, v in accounts.iteritems()})
```

Comment: Thank you. All answers are correct. I ended up using @dugres.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from datetime import datetime

d = defaultdict(list, {'003': [('Biology', 'A', '04/18/2013'), ('Irdu', 'A', '04/17/2013')], '002': [('Biology', 'A', '03/01/2013'), ('Math', 'C', '01/10/2013'), ('Math', 'C', '03/10/2013')], '001': [('Biology', 'B', '05/01/2013'), ('Literature', 'B', '03/02/2013'), ('Math', 'A', '02/20/2013')]})

def key(entry):
    _, _, date_string = entry
    date_entry = datetime.strptime(date_string, '%m/%d/%Y').date()
    return (date_entry.year, date_entry.month, date_entry.day)

{k: sorted(v, key=key) for k,v in d.iteritems()}
>>> {
'001': [('Math', 'A', '02/20/2013'),
    ('Literature', 'B', '03/02/2013'),
    ('Biology', 'B', '05/01/2013')],
'002': [('Math', 'C', '01/10/2013'),
    ('Biology', 'A', '03/01/2013'),
    ('Math', 'C', '03/10/2013')],
'003': [('Irdu', 'A', '04/17/2013'), ('Biology', 'A', '04/18/2013')]
}
```

Comment: Thank you. All answers are correct. I ended up using @dugres.